# Equivalent of auto_arima function of R in Stata

Tags: regression, time-series, stata, arima, dynamic-regression

I am building a dynamic regression model in Stata which basically has this form:
$$Y = a_1x_1 + a_2x_2 +... + e$$
where the error $e$ is then modeled as ARIMA process.

Is there a command to find optimal ARIMA order for the error? In R we can use the `auto_arima` function to do it; how can I do this in Stata?

Comment: Isn't it auto.arima()? Also, you don't have any lags of $y$ in the equation.

Comment: auto.arima()? Is that a function in Stata? I didnt find any in my version .. is that in a new one?

Lags of y would come in the arima model of error.

Comment: I believe it is called auto.arima() in R (part of the forecast package), and not auto_arima().

Answer (score 6):

There's no automated Stata version as far as I know.

The Hyndman-Khandakar algorithm that auto.arima() uses to pick p,d, and q is described [here](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/8/7). The basic steps are:

> 1. The number of differences d is determined using repeated KPSS tests.
> 2. The values of p and q are then chosen by minimizing the AICc after
>      differencing the data d times. Rather than considering every
>      possible combination of p and q, the algorithm uses a stepwise
>      search to traverse the model space.
>
> (a) The best model (with smallest AICc) is selected from the following
>   four:
>
> - ARIMA(2,d,2)
> - ARIMA(0,d,0)
> - ARIMA(1,d,0)
> - ARIMA(0,d,1).
>
> If d=0 then the constant c is included; if d≥1 then the constant c is
>   set to zero. This is called the "current model".
>
> (b) Variations on the current model are considered:
>
> - vary p and/or q from the current model by ±1
> - include/exclude c from the current model.
>
> The best model considered so far (either the
>   current model, or one of these variations) becomes the new current
>   model.
>
> (c) Repeat Step 2(b) until no lower AICc can be found.

All of the tests/statistics involved can be calculated with Stata, so you could achieve something similar by hand, and automate it with a bit more effort. For KPSS, use Chris Baum's `kpss` from SSC. You can get the corrected AIC by using `estat ic` and [this formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion#AICc).